# Error during precompiling DataFrames.jl: UndefVarError: ComposedFunction not defined

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm using Julia 1.5.3 and last versions of module DataFrames.jl (v0.22.0) and Compat.jl (v3.23.0).
I've added DataFrames into my project enviroment as usual:

```
]add DataFrames
```

Last time I've used DataFrames package in July 2020.
Now when i'm trying to use (call `using DataFrames`) the package I have an error:

```
[ Info: Precompiling DataFrames [a93c6f00-e57d-5684-b7b6-d8193f3e46c0]
ERROR: LoadError: LoadError: UndefVarError: ComposedFunction not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at C:\Users\yzh\.julia\packages\DataFrames\X0xNW\src\other\utils.jl:82
 [2] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:380
 [3] include at .\Base.jl:368 [inlined]
 [4] include(::String) at C:\Users\yzh\.julia\packages\DataFrames\X0xNW\src\DataFrames.jl:1
 [5] top-level scope at C:\Users\yzh\.julia\packages\DataFrames\X0xNW\src\DataFrames.jl:94
 [6] include(::Function, ::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:380
 [7] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:368
 [8] top-level scope at none:2
 [9] eval at .\boot.jl:331 [inlined]
 [10] eval(::Expr) at .\client.jl:467
 [11] top-level scope at .\none:3
in expression starting at C:\Users\yzh\.julia\packages\DataFrames\X0xNW\src\other\utils.jl:79
in expression starting at C:\Users\yzh\.julia\packages\DataFrames\X0xNW\src\DataFrames.jl:94
```

*But tests `Pkg.test("DataFrames")` have passed corretly without an errors!*

I think I have some troubles with the Compat - package. When I'm trying to export `ComposedFunction` separetly:

```
using Compat: ComposedFunction
```

I also have an error:

```
UndefVarError: ComposedFunction not defined
in include_string at base\loading.jl:1088
```

I've tried several things:

- remove the packages and install again;
- `]up`
- `Pkg.resolve`
- update Julia from 1.5.2 to 1.5.3
- restart computer, of course
- delete all folders besides "dev" and "environment" from .julia directory

but the errors still exist.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you show what version of Compat.jl you have using `] st Compat`? I have 3.23.0 and when I write `using Compat; Compat.ComposedFunction` it does not error. Also in Julia 1.5.3.

Comment: Hi!

```Project DashVis v0.1.0
Status `C:\Users\yzh\.julia\dev\DashVis\Project.toml`
  [34da2185] Compat v3.23.0
```

Colleague of mine doesn't have an error to. So.. i'm confused

Comment: He-he...I've re-run Atom in administrator mode and all errors disappeared.
Now everything works without admin mode also.
Magic...

Answer (score 2):

I've re-run Atom again in administrator mode and all errors disappeared. Now everything works without admin mode also. Magic.

Comment: Indeed Atom is problematic. I recommend you to switch to VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i'll think about it !

Comment: Just for more background Atom development is being slowed down as Microsoft now owns GitHub (creators of Atom) so the focus is on VS Code. Running Julia in VS Code is  a very nice experience now.